# Sum column values across multiple dataframes

Tags: linux, columns, gnu

Suppose I have 3 dataframes (independent .txt files):

```
        Acamar   Begalb     Caspri 
Acamar  0.1      0.0        6.3
Begalb  0.33     8.3        0.0
Caspri  1.4      0.617      2.4

        Acamar   Begalb    Caspri 
Acamar  0.5      3.2        0.1
Begalb  0.0      2.1        0.5
Caspri  4.2      0.0        1.5

        Acamar   Begalb    Caspri 
Acamar  0.5      3.2        0.1
Begalb  0.0      2.1        0.5
Caspri  4.2      0.0        1.5
```

I want to sum the column values across the 3 dataframes so that I get:

```
           Acamar   Begalb    Caspri 
    Acamar  1.1      6.4        6.5
    Begalb  0.33     12.5       1
    Caspri  9.8      0.617      5.4
```

Using datamash like this:

```
cat *.txt | datamash --headers groupby 1 sum 2-4
```

Populates all my columns with 0 and returns an error saying:

```
invalid numeric value in field 2: 'Acamar'
```

Does anyone know how to help, using datamash or something else?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works:

```
paste -d"\n" *.txt |
    sed -r '1!{/^(\s+[[:alnum:]])+/d;}' |
    LC_ALL=C ./datamash-1.3/datamash --headers groupby 1 sum 2-4
```

Result:

```
GroupBy()       sum(Acamar)     sum(Begalb)     sum(Caspri)
Acamar  1.1     6.4     6.5
Begalb  0.33    12.5    1
Caspri  9.8     0.617   5.4
```

The main issue here is solved both by `paste`, `sed` line and `LC_ALL` value.

- **`paste`** join files *line by line* (`cat *.txt` will join files one  after the other, inserting header lines inside datas)
- **`sed`** line removes header lines except the first occurrence ([source](https://www.unix.com/302533341-post3.html))

  - I assumed that header lines are a sequence of blank characters (`\s+`) followed by alphanumeric characters (`[[:alnum:]])+`)
- **`LC_ALL`** is a variable managing the locale, and will prevent any misinterpretation of the dot in values

Also add `-W` if the fields are separated with **spaces** rather than tabs.

Comment: this is perfect! thank you very much for your help :)